# Unexpected behavior of bash script used to sync dotfiles

Tags: command-line, bash, symlink

I'm using essentially [this script](https://github.com/michaeljsmalley/dotfiles) for keeping my dotfiles under version control. I recently added a `snippets` folder inside my `emacs.d` directory and listed it as one of the things that should be symlinked to from my home directory. However, when I run the script now it creates a symlink to `snippets` inside `snippets` itself.

Here's the relevant bit of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
############################
# .make.sh
# This script creates symlinks from the home directory to any desired dotfiles in ~/dotfiles
############################

########## Variables

dir=~/.dotfiles                    # dotfiles directory
olddir=~/.dotfiles_old             # old dotfiles backup directory
files="bash_profile gitignore gitconfig zshrc jrnl_config emacs.d/init.el emacs.d/custom.el emacs.d/snippets scripts/makeadate.js config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications config/karabiner/karabiner.json"    # list of files/folders to symlink in homedir
##########

# create dotfiles_old in homedir
echo -n "Creating $olddir for backup of any existing dotfiles in ~ ..."
mkdir -p $olddir
echo "done"

# change to the dotfiles directory
echo -n "Changing to the $dir directory ..."
cd $dir
echo "done"

# move any existing dotfiles in homedir to dotfiles_old directory, then create symlinks from the homedir to any files in the ~/dotfiles directory specified in $files
for file in $files; do
    echo "Moving any existing dotfiles from ~ to $olddir"
    mv ~/.$file $olddir
    echo "Creating symlink to $file in home directory."
    ln -s $dir/$file ~/.$file
done
```

So, before running the script, `~/.dotfiles/emacs.d/snippets` contains only two subdirectories, `latex-mode` and `mhtml-mode`. After running the script, it contains a new symlink to `~/.dotfiles/emacs.d/snippets`. I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact that one of the values that the variable `$file` is taking is a directory. But I don't know exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If `target` is an already existing directory, then the command `ln -s source target` will create a link `target/source` in that directory, pointing to the original `source`. That's what's going on here: the directory `.emacs.d/snippets/` exists at the start, and you're running the command

```
ln ~/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/snippets ~/.emacs.d/snippets
```

which creates a link in the existing `snippets` to the other `snippets`.

You could do `ln -s ~/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/snippets/* ~/.emacs.d/snippets` instead. Or delete everything in `.emacs.d` and do `ln -s ~/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/* ~/.emacs.d`. (Obviously make copies first in case something goes wrong.) Or perhaps even delete `.emacs.d` and create a new version which is just a symlink.